# Cannot install Az and AzureRM modules at the same time

Tags: powershell

I am trying to import the module Az.compute in my Windows Powershell. I have earlier imported the module AzureRM, since I need it for some automation tasks.

But I'm getting the error message:

`PS X:\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\PowerShell> Import-Module -Name Az.compute
WARNUNG: AzureRM.Profile already loaded. Az and AzureRM modules cannot be imported in the same session or used in the
same script or runbook. If you are running PowerShell in an environment you control you can use the 'Uninstall-AzureRm'
 cmdlet to remove all AzureRm modules from your machine. If you are running in Azure Automation, take care that none of
 your runbooks import both Az and AzureRM modules. More information can be found here:
https://aka.ms/azps-migration-guide.
Import-Module : AzureRM.Profile already loaded. Az and AzureRM modules cannot be imported in the same session or used
in the same script or runbook. If you are running PowerShell in an environment you control you can use the
'Uninstall-AzureRm' cmdlet to remove all AzureRm modules from your machine. If you are running in Azure Automation,
take care that none of your runbooks import both Az and AzureRM modules. More information can be found here:
https://aka.ms/azps-migration-guide.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ Import-Module -Name Az.compute
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (AzureRM.Profile...igration-guide.:String) [Import-Module], RuntimeExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AzureRM.Profile already loaded. Az and AzureRM modules cannot be imported in the same se
   ssion or used in the same script or runbook. If you are running PowerShell in an environment you control you can u
  se the 'Uninstall-AzureRm' cmdlet to remove all AzureRm modules from your machine. If you are running in Azure Aut
 omation, take care that none of your runbooks import both Az and AzureRM modules. More information can be found he
re: https://aka.ms/azps-migration-guide.,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand⏎`

My question is, how can I import the Az.compute module while having the AzureRM module installed since I need both modules?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Ronny Forberger

Tried to import the Az.compute module.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the short answer is no. BUT - you can install the Az modules and then use Enable-AzureRmAlias, if you want to support your old scripts and functions.

You need to remove the AzureRM module first and then install the Az module.

Of course you should update all scripts to support the new module, sonce the old module will not receive any updates.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/enable-azurermalias?view=azps-2.3.2

Comment: Thanks, I used Update-AzureRmVmss.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and use AzureRm and Az modules at the same time but in different sessions. When you need to use Az module, open a new session with Az cmdlet, the same must be done with AzureRm module. Use a new session for each module.